# Filter all the data - big data load

Tags: interaction-design, filter, data, dashboard

I'm creating a platform that has a lot of company data, around 200,000 companies with 1000 branches each, so it's a lot.

When we load the platform we usually don't show anything until we have loaded all the data, after we show all the data we have the ability to select/deselect companies, and if a user deselects one company then the request to the database will be sent for ALL DATA minus one company, so it would take a lot of time to show anything. Until we fix the database infrastructure, how would be a good way to solve this problem?

A possible solution that some platforms have is they don't allow you to deselect after the load or limit selection above 50 companies or so...

Comment: What solutions have you tried and what are the problems with them? Without those details there is not much clarity on the question or problem. And without details on a current implementation this is more an implementation question, which is off topic.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a developer, but may be the performance will not be affected if instead of reloading the whole data minus deselected you just set the row's visibility to "hidden" via css ( or display: none)? Also, do you paginate or scroll? Pagination or "load more" Button also improve performance.